# Using two IP connections in parallel for resilient delivery

Tags: ip, ethernet, tunneling, bonding, lte

I have a mobile Linux server with two LTE connections to the internet, via different providers.

The mobile server also acts as a router for other devices, currently using masquerading on just a single LTE connection.

There is also a central Linux server, on high-speed internet connection.

I want to use both of the LTE connections redundantly, so that all internet-bound packets are sent via both LTE connections, via the central server.

What is the best way of achieving this?

I have considered using bonding, with Ethernet-over-IP to the central server on each of the LTE connections, but that seems wasteful.

Is there an equivalent of bonding, but at the IP, rather than ethernet, level?

Comment: Have you read through [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53499/how-to-merge-multiple-internet-connections-into-one) and tried any of the suggestions there?

Comment: @dirkt I believe that interface bonding is an ethernet-layer function, not an IP-layer function.  Can you link to me to any evidence that may correct me?  The first few Google links for "bond gre tunnel linux" are laments of people who can't make it work.

Comment: @dirkt I'm writing a multi-bearer TUN VPN, while waiting for an answer that will let me abandon it.